# Openvpn packet and NetworkManager VPN trouble with DNS and with call function

Tags: linux, dns, networkmanager, openvpn, systemd-networkd

Spent a lot of time to figure out what's going on. But still issue not a clear.
Summarize, installed OVPN packets for NetworkManager. And installed clear openvpn with new version 3, so have openvpn, openvpn3. And packet to work with NetworkManager(.ovpn config). Also was installed update-resolve-service.

This is config:

```
remote domain_name 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-nocache
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 5
rcvbuf 262144
sndbuf 262144
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo no
proto udp
key-direction 1
script-security 2
setenv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
up-restart
up /vpn/iptab_killswitch.sh
up-restart
down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
down /vpn/iptab_default.sh
down-pre
```

When I use commandline to start vpn, it's works fine for modifiying iptables(for killswitch)  but it's stil issue with leaky DNS.

killswitch:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
sudo iptables -t nat --flush
sudo iptables -t nat --delete-chain
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -i lo
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o lo
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -d server/24 -o wlp2s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 443
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -s server/24 -i wlp2s0 -p udp -m udp --sport 443
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -i tun0
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o tun0
```

resolvectl:

default:

```
Link 2 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: no         
      DNSSEC setting: no         
    DNSSEC supported: no         
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

when I use "sudo openvpn --config /path_to_my_config.ovpn":

```
Link 54 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no  

Link 2 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: no         
      DNSSEC setting: no         
    DNSSEC supported: no         
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

When using NetworkManager to connect to my config:

```
Link 55 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: no         
      DNSSEC setting: no         
    DNSSEC supported: no         
  Current DNS Server: 10.64.104.1
         DNS Servers: 10.64.104.1
          DNS Domain: ~.         

Link 2 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

So, when I use NetworkManager it's modified DNS, and ignore "up" command inside .ovpn.
Any service from internet see VPN DNS. When I use clear openvpn client - it's use script inside the config, but don't modify DNS.

How can I setting my VPN with blocking leak DNS and with function killswitch?